# Phonegap Sqlite on iOS not working

Tags: ios, sqlite, cordova, phonegap-build

I am using Phonegap Build (cli-5.2.0) to build my Android / iOS app that i install on my tablets (iOS 9).

I have some problems to store some data in the database, not all.

On Android, the app is working fine.

When instead of the plugin io.litehelpers.cordova.sqlite (0.7.7 npm) i use the native sqlite database of the tablet, the iOS app is also working fine.

So the problem come from the plugin somewhere :)

Is somebody see something wrong in the PhonegapBuild log below?

http://pastebin.com/JfE9RSJd

Thanks
Guillaume.

Comment: This appears to be a problem with the plugin. Discuss your issue with the author of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was due to a code inside the executeSQL callback, so the transaction failled.